# Hibernate uses 255 length for Blob

Tags: java, hibernate

I have a class which has a property annotated with @Lob. Hibernate uses 255 as a length by default - verified this using HSQLDB logs. Shouldn't hibernate use the default value depending of the type of the database?

```
@Entity
public class A {

    @Id
    @Column
    @GeneratedValue
    long id

    @Column
    @Lob
    @Convert(converter = LobCustomModelConverter)
    CustomModel model
}
```

Converter:

```
@Converter
class LobCustomModelConverter implements AttributeConverter<CustomModel, byte[]> {

    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper()

    @Override
    byte[] convertToDatabaseColumn(CustomModel model) {
        mapper.writeValueAsBytes(model)
    }

    @Override
    CustomModel convertToEntityAttribute(byte[] s) {
        mapper.readValue(s, CustomModel)
    }

}
```

Comment: "Shouldn't hibernate use the default value depending of the type of the database?" Why should it?

Comment: I think 255 is not enough since Lobs are considered large, just my opinion.

Comment: Certainly, but that doesn't mean that Hibernate won't do weird things and disregard the database entirely. What version of Hibernate are you using, this may be relevant: https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-2614